# Sampling Permutations of [1,2,3,...,N] for large N

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, sample-data, large-data

I have to solve [the Travelling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) using a [genetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) that I will have to write for **homework**.

The problem consists of 52 cities. Therefore, the search space is `52!`. I need to randomly sample (say) 1000 permutations of `range(1, 53)` as individuals for the initial population of my genetic algorithm.

In order to do this, I tried:

```
>>> random.sample(itertools.permutations(range(1, 53)), 1000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/random.py", line 314, in sample
    n = len(population)
TypeError: object of type 'itertools.permutations' has no len()
```

So I tried

```
>>> random.sample(list(itertools.permutations(range(1, 53))), 1000)
```

However, given that `52!` is VERY large, the `list` operation is maxing out the memory and swap space on my computer. I can't just pick the first 1000 permutations generated by `itertools.permutations` because it's very deterministic and that would bias my genetic algorithm.

Is there a better way to achieve this sampling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to permute at all. Call `random.sample(range(52), 52)` 1000 times.

P.S.: You really should use zero-based indexing (`range(52)` as opposed to `range(1, 53)`) in all your work. Things generally work out better that way.

Comment: I totally agree with your zero based indexing, but the indeces here represent the City IDs and my Prof decided that he wants to start from 1... So I'm trying to stay true to his convention

Comment: It's been my experience that you should just do it your own way and convert it to your professor's shitty conventions in your output statements.

Comment: Wait, for a random _permutation_ shouldn't this be `p = range(10); random.shuffle(p)`? `random.sample` will duplicate some values and omit others. But perhaps you're saying that these don't actually have to be permutations...

Comment: @senderle random.sample works *without* replacement do it does indeed produce a permutation.  When the sample size is the same as the population size, it is equivalent to random.shuffle() on the population (except that shuffle with shuffle in-place and sample will leave the original unchanged).